# Can any one explain the request library in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

```
 var request = require('request');
 request('http://www.google.com', function(error, response, body) {
     console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
     console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
     console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
 })
```

1. I am confused whether we can rewrite by saying `response.error`,body do the naming conventions must be same can we  change
2. How  the function here works.  How can it know to pass the first parameter as error and second as response

Comment: That's just how request library works. You give it a function of three parameters, and it will call it with error, response and body, in that order. You can name them whatever you want. If you name them `(response, error, body)`, then it'll be confusing, because `response` will contain the error and `error` will contain the response.

Answer (score 2):

Request expects a certain function signature to be used. In this case a function with the parameters `error`, `response` and `body`. These kind of functions are often called the `callback` function.

When a request is finished, the `request` library calls the function you have designed as its callback function.

Basically `request` forces you to use this function signature and you can nothing do about it.

Nowadays it is more common for libraries to use `promises` or work with `async/await`. Which offer a more flexible way to act on the response of the function called.

Answer (score 0):

```
 request('http://www.google.com', function(error, response, body) {
```

})

Take **request** as function which return response and body. 
`function(error,response,body){}` is **callback**.Which mean when request() complete this`function(error,response,body){}`
is going to run. 
It is syntax of callback that first argument is always error. If you encounter callbacks in future then you will notice every callback have error as first argument.Which is error caused while running the function here function is request().It(error) can be null if no error occur during execution of request().
Then after error, response and body come which are the output of request() function.

You can change and keep what ever name to them example

```
1 function(error,response,body){}
2 function(e,resp,rbody){}
3 function(response,error,body){}
4 function(response,body,error){}
```

these not cause you an error all are same statements but to access error in

```
1 function(error,response,body){console.log(error)}
2 function(e,resp,rbody){console.log(e)}
3 function(response,error,body){console.log(response)} 
4 function(response,error,body){console.log(response)}
```

I will suggest you to read from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm